# Check if line got executed with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, testing, rspec

I have a worker that sends email to users when new feedback pops in. I wanted to allow user to not agree to that (with Shih Tzu flags). Question is: how can I test (with Rspec) if the `FedbackMailer.new_feedback` line gets executed?

```
  account.users.each do |user|
    return if (user.no_notifications || user.just_summary)

    FeedbackMailer.new_feedback(account.id, feedback_id, user.id).deliver_later
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rspec-mocks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs).

```rb
mailer = instance_double
allow(FeedbackMailer).to receive(:new_feedback).with(account_id, feedback_id, user_id).and_return(mailer)
allow(mailer).to receive(:deliver_later)

## do stuff ##

expect(mailer).to have_received(:deliver_later)
```

You can also ignore the `.with` if you haven't the arguments to pass in that moment.

---

Another solution is to set a config `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test` and check if the delivery counts have changed.

```rb
expect {
 ## code that deliver the email
}.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your logic is encapsulated in following method in class `MyClass`

```
class MyClass
  def my_method
    account.users.each do |user|
      return if (user.no_notifications || user.just_summary)

      FeedbackMailer.new_feedback(account.id, feedback_id, user.id).deliver_later
    end
  end
end

RSpec.describe MyClass, type: :model do
  context "#my_method" do
    it "should send new feedback" do
      user_obj = create_user

      expect(user_obj.no_notifications).to be_falsey
      #OR
      #expect(user_obj.just_summary).to be_falsey

      account_obj = create_account
      account_obj.users << user_obj

      expect(account_obj.users).to include(user_obj)


      expect(FeedbackMailer).to receive(:new).with(account_obj.id, feedback_id, user_obj.id)
      # OR in case you don't have feedback_id then you can use
      # expect(FeedbackMailer).to receive(:new).with(account_obj.id, kind_of(Numeric), user_obj.id)

      # You should also setup expectation here that `FeedbackMailer` gets enqueued to ensure
      # that your method also gets invoked and the job also gets enqueued.

      subject.my_method
    end
  end
end
```

Hope that helps. Thanks.